Decoupling capacitors for operational amplifiers
when in the refence design of an amplifier (for example OPA856) we see the + sign in a capacitor schematic, does this necessarily means we should use electrolytic capacitors?

If there is no positive sign, it means it is ceramic capacitor?

You must provide a link to the image. It's part of the rules for this site.

@ Andy aka, Hi Andy, thank, DONE

If you do use a polarized capacitor note that the lower 6.8 μF capacitor will be reversed biased if $V_{S-}$ is negative with respect to ground (as it usually is).


does this necessarily means we should use electrolytic capacitors?

A better starting point for decoupling capacitors on the IC is this: -

I've put red boxes around the two surface mount bypass capacitors to emphasize their importance. In other words focus on these capacitors as being vital. This is supplemented by these words in the data sheet (red box): -

In the blue box are recommendations for the capacitors mentioned in your question and clearly, the data sheet isn't necessarily recommending that electrolytics be used. It just says that they should be good for low frequencies and that usually means electrolytics but, in many applications, electrolytic capacitors are not permitted so, it's not a problem if unpolarized ceramic capacitors are used.

If there is no positive sign, it means it is ceramic capacitor?

No, it doesn't. A ceramic capacitor is unpolarized but, so are many other types. Neither does it mean that an electrolytic cannot be used but, it may be indicating that you need to analyse the circuit to ensure that an electrolytic capacitor can be used.

@ Andy aka, thank you very much, I just check Mouser and Digi key, and noticed there is not 6.8 uF C0G available in the market and the closet one is 10 UF?!! is that ok (using 10 uF instead)?

@Andromeda you don't need to use C0G for the capacitors in the blue box. C0G are really good caps and are wasted here but, you should use C0G for the caps in the red box i.e. 100 nF C0G. I would use X7R dielectric for the larger valued capacitors.

@Andromeda: The capacitance of class 2 dielectric ceramics (example X7R) is highly voltage dependent. Choose a higher value to allow for the loss due to bias voltage. Choosing a capacitor with a higher voltage rating will not work.


the + sign in a capacitor schematic, does this necessarily means we should use electrolytic capacitors?

No, not necessarily.  It simply means the circuit designer chose a polarised component in this particular case.  It does not mean you must use a polarised component.  Note that electrolytic capacitors are not the only type of capacitor that may be polarised, tantalum capacitors are also often polarised.
Also, not all electrolytic capacitors are polarised, you can get non-polarised electrolytic capacitors.

If there is no positive sign, it means it is ceramic capacitor?

No, not necessarily, it just means that this particular capacitor is non-polarised, it does not imply that the capacitor is ceramic.  There are many other types of capacitors that are non-polarised, eg: polyester, polypropylene, mica.
Polarity & insulation material are just two parameters associated with capacitors.  If you include other parameters, for example physical form factor, physical dimensions, connection type, temperature rating, DC voltage rating, AC voltage rating, current rating, frequency response, case material (just to name a few), then you can see that there are thousands of different types of capacitors that are possible.
If you are building a circuit designed by someone else, rather than relying on just the schematic to select components, also refer to the Bill of Materials, which should give detailed ordering information about each component.

@ Neil_UK and @Fabio Barone thank you for the nice explanation, in the datasheet it is mentioned that I should use C0G- and NPO-type decoupling capacitors. In other part is is mentioned that it should be low ESR. Are these types of capacitor polarized? for example this is an example: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/kemet/C1206C104F3GEC7800/8644665. It seems the smallest package for range of uF is 1206?!

Yes, NPO caps are physically large.  X7R caps are smaller, but not as "good".  This ref may help your understanding:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/495609/341959
